# What kind of scripts are being used to detect country of the site visitor and redirect to specific localization?

Tags: php, html, redirect, localization

My website is in Russian and English. I wanted to know what kind of php script or other (maybe a plugin) could you recommend in order to redirect the users from Russia (or other Russian speaking countries) to the Russian version of the site.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the Russian version a completely different site? Or is it the same site that just needs a particular variable set to indicate the language?

Comment: See http://www.htaccesstools.com/redirection-by-language/

Comment: Also, always give your users the option to set their own language. You don't want to frustrate russian-speakers in north america, english-speakers in russia, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this, using a HTTP Header or using an IP Lookup database.

Using a HTTP Header you can check something like...

```
<?php
     switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']){
         case "ru":
             // Serve Russian Page
             break;
         default:
             // Serve English Page
             break;
     }
?>
```

<strike>Or you could use an IP Lookup database by doing something like...</strike>

```
<?php
    $return = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']);
    $returndata = explode("\n", $return);
    if( $returndata[0] == "Country: RUSSIAN FEDERATION (RU)" ){
        // Serve Russian Page
    }else{
        // Serve English Page
    }
?>
```

Using the HTTP Header should be better as this is what is was designed for, it should also work when the user is behind a proxy server (depends on the type though). However it's up to you which method you use.

**EDIT: It's probably best to use the first method**

Comment: this is not working for all ips. try this ip 188.2.32.213. it is serbia, novi sad. that api does not see it!

Comment: I strongly recommend a `default` case. Otherwise, users with an unknown language see no content at all.

Comment: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is the right way to detect this case. Don't rely on GEOIP lookups, they are not reliable indicators of the visitor's preferred language.

Comment: @AlexHowansky When writing a summary I realised how much more sense it makes to use the HTTP Header method - also a large number of IPs are unknown to the service.

Comment: GEOIP lookups *are* notoriously inaccurate, but there's no reason why you shouldn't use that as a *fallback* method if no `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` was set.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

And then simple

`if(geoip_country_name_by_name ($ip) <>'Rusia') {header("Location:". $english) else {header ("Location:". $russian}`